# Sliding Header/NavBar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a header but I am stuck at 2 things.

1. How do I get it all positioned properly? What I want is it to be positioned as a header with a navbar at the bottom of it, then in that navbar I want a div that I can make slide around and I want x amount of tabs.
2. How would I make the div slide left/right using JavaScript/JQuery? Sorry if it doesn't make sense.

My code is:

```
 <body>  
     <div class="header">
      <div id="topHeader"> </div>
        <div class="navBar">
        //buttons/text here
        <div id="slider"> </div>
        </div>
     </div>
 </body>
```

I have tried using positioning (absolute/relative) but when I make the navBar relative it doesn't stay at the bottom but if I make both it and the slider absolute, the slider doesn't stay in the navBar. Is there any other way to accomplish it?

Comment: do you want us to write full code for you ? show what have you tried ?

Comment: please, try to post the code you are having which is not working. This is not the way to ask question. You might get downlvotes. We would help you in solving the question but we won't help in writing the code from scratch..

Comment: Added what I tried so far, I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to understand how to make it work. However, here it goes.

The css for header would be:

```
.header {
display: block; // for that overall div..
}
```

Then you are having a top header, that would be more like a top header under which you want the nav bar. Ok for that you said you want it to be as header. Then just write it the way it is! And it will be used as a header, I mean just add some margins and paddings so that it has some distance from other objects.

```
#topHeader {
margin: 5px; // overall 5px pixel for all sides.
padding: 2px; // 2 pixel padding..
}
```

The nav bar, was the one with may buttons and texts that you will be using as hyperlinks to other pages. Right? So try using something like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>First text</li>
  <li>Second text</li>
  <li>Third text</li>
</ul>
```

Now, show them all in a line. Because you wanted them in line, the list items will be shown in a line instead of being shown under each other as default. The `x` tabs will be the amount of the `li` used in the list, and it will show all the buttons or what ever you were trying to show. To do that the CSS is:

```
li {
display: inline;
}
```

To remove the bullet style, use this:

```
ul {
list-style: none;
}
```

This way the navbar will be shown in a line as other websites show.

**Second question:**

The sliders slide with the help of mouse, not jQuery (Just kidding). You can use scroll bars buddy, jQuery is used to scroll or slide, but that hides once slided. You will be able to see it but when it will scroll back it will hide, and go out of the page untill you slide it back again. You can just stick to the scroll bars to scroll or slide.

That's all!

**jQuery slider:**

From jQuery API if you check the `slide()` you will find out, that any event on any element would cause a slide (that will slide the element up and down) in some element.

Here would be an example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#slider").click(function () {
    $(".navBar").slideToggle(1000); // the time consumed is 1 sec = 1000 milliseconds.
  }
});
```

You can see, that a click on the element with `id="slider"` would slide the element with `class="navBar"` and the slide will consume the time of 1 second.

**Advice or Suggestion:**

I would like to advise you to first learn the basics about the codes that you will use. They are easily searchable via Google, Bing or any other search engine. Because if you will post questions that you know nothing about would cause downvotes for you. That's ridiculous I know. So please when you are going to use `jquery` and know nothing about it, please try to go to [Google](http://www.google.com) and write this search item `jquery` if nothing found then append `tutorial` to the search query and find it. Best tutorial would be found on the site of the developer. Like you can learn jQuery on [jquery.com](http://jquery.com) and JSON at [json.org](http://json.org).

Comment: So I knew how to make the navBar, I just cannot get it positioned properly. An example of what I want the layout to look like is bukkit.org see how their navbar is layed out? And then is there no way to make a div slide left/right when something is hovered over or clicked on?

Comment: What I told you, was just that! The list will be displayed like a bar, and also it depends how much effort you make on CSS for that. And also, yes there is an option for that too. use jQuery slide. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_slide.asp

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not good at explaining. When I try to add the slider it gets messed up since the slider is a separate div, what you're explaining is without a slider, and then the jquery slide there isn't the effect I am looking for, again, sorry I am not good at explaining, but I want the div to move left or right when an element in the list is hovered over.

Comment: Its ok, no one is perfect! Wait let me add that for you :)

Comment: I learned the "skin" of many languages, but I am working on learning the "depth". One thing that is confusing me is that on the jQuery slide, it looks like it only does up/down, not right/left. Any explanation to that?

Comment: Nope! For that you will need `toggle()`. That will hide show the elements. You can try `fadeToggle()`. But they all work alike. Its upto you to style the code. :) Gud luck!